# Convert PowerPoint to MP4

Tags: c#, powerpoint, mp4

I am looking at making an application to convert PowerPoint presentations to MP4 files. I would like to write it in C#. I have everything built except for the converting part. I have seen some people talk about using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint

Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are aware that PowerPoint can save directly to MP4? I assume this is for batch conversion?  I believe Office Interop usually involves opening an instance of PowerPoint in the background and giving it tasks - you might as well create a macro in PowerPoint itself. The alternative would be to write your own PowerPoint XML parser to render pptx files out to MP4, or find an open source one.

Comment: Also "I have everything built except for the converting part" is an interesting statement. What does this application do, if not convert?

Comment: Yes, I am aware that PowerPoint can, but I need to convert large amounts of PowerPoints over at a time. By me saying I have everything built, I meant that I have the interface and the ability to browse and find files setup, I could have been clearer in my initial question.

Comment: You can do it you need to have PowerPoint installed on you system and reference office Interop libraries specifically core and powerpoint